# How to add recovery option directly into the main menu instead of going to "Advanced options for ubuntu"?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Basically booting into the default ubuntu option on my hp omen causes the computer to freeze, and the only way to boot successfully into ubuntu is to go through recovery options first then choosing resume boot.
I'd like to replace the default ubuntu option to use the recovery option instead.

I found this solution: GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-53-generic (recovery mode)" (including quotes).
But I'd like to add it directly into the main menu.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Every problem has two solutions: the solution for everyone, and the solution for you right now.

The solution for everyone (including you) to [report a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en) so that the developers can figure out why this is happening and fix it.  This takes time, but it will also save time for you in the future, when you stop having to apply local workarounds.

The solution for you right now is to figure out which kernel command-line argument used in the recovery mode boot entry makes the boot successfull -- probably `nomodeset` -- and then edit `/etc/default/grub` to add it to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.  Then run `sudo update-grub`.  Then the regular default boot menu entry should be able to boot your system, and you won't need to change which menu item is the default, and you won't need to manually select 'resume' on every boot.

(And to answer your literal question, edit `/etc/default/grub`, add `GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y`, and run `sudo update-grub` to get a flat boot menu without submenus.  I don't think there's a way to have a submenu for all older kernel versions, but put have the latest kernel recovery mode option in the top-level menu, not without painful rewriting of grub.cfg generating shell scripts.)